# Getting empty object in axios GET request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, get, typeerror, axios

I am pulling posts from WordPress blog site. But when I console log state `posts` and `response` in `.then()` I get `Response` as `empty object [object object]` and `state` as `undefined`.

Where am I going wrong?

I am also getting following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Post from './Post/Post';

class Blog extends Component {

    state = {
        posts: []
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        axios.get("https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/sites/ishhaanpatel.wordpress.com/posts")
        .then( response => {
            this.setState({posts: response.posts});
            console.log("Here are the posts: "+ this.state.posts);
            console.log("Here is the response: "+ response);

        });
    }

    render(){
         const posts = this.state.posts.map( post => {
             return <Post title={post.title} key={post.ID} author={post.author.name}  />;
         });
        return (
            <div>
                {posts}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Blog;
```

Comment: When you set state is `posts` an empty or undefined array?

Comment: just `console.log`  the response... axios response return the data in the object data key.

Comment: when I only return `response`, `console.log` still giving me `empty object` but this time I got state value as `empty object` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having problem with `asyncronous`.

`setState` is `async`. So, you won't immediately get the value in `this.state.posts`.

To solve this problem you can use callbacks as follows:

```
this.setState({ posts: response.posts }, () => {
    console.log(this.state.posts);
});
```

Also your posts is nested inside `response.data`. So, your `setState` should look something like:

```
this.setState({ posts: response.data.posts }, () => {
    console.log(this.state.posts);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data is nested inside the `response.data` object.

Update

```
this.setState({posts: response.posts});
```

to

```
this.setState({posts: response.data.posts});
```

Axios returns a HTTP response object which contains additional information about the response.